# Can prettier replace var with let

Tags: typescript, prettier

I am using prettier to format my Typescript code on save.
I would like to know if there is an option to replace var with let using prettier.

This is the code I use to format a hole project with

```
"format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"src/**/*.js\"",
```

Answer (score 4):

Prettier is a code formatter. It doesn't do things like that. See "[What Prettier is not concerned about](https://prettier.io/docs/en/rationale.html#what-prettier-is-_not_-concerned-about)" in its docs.